# jPopUpMenu Change rollover background

Tags: java, colors, background, jpopupmenu, jmenuitem

I would like to change the background color of my `jMenuItems` on a rollover event :

[image]

Now it's blue, I want it white, how can I do ? (I use netbeans GUI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
UIManager.put("MenuItem.selectionBackground", Color.WHITE);
```

Problem is this will change the color for all menu items, even those added to a JMenu.

To control which menu items are changed you will need to create a custom MenuItem UI to replace the default. You will then need to modify the code to use your custom selection background color.

Comment: Somewhere before you create your components.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to be able to use different colors in different parts of an app. Rather than use UIManager to change the LookAndFeel, I extended `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI`:-

```
public class CustomMenuUI extends BasicMenuItemUI {
    public CustomMenuUI(Color color){
        super.selectionBackground = color;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to set the UI for your JMenuItem:-

```
CustomMenuUI menuUI = new CustomMenuUI(Color.WHITE);
jMenuItem.setUI(menuUI);
```